# What is the special name of vectors like $\langle0,1,0,0,0\rangle$ or $\langle1,0,0\rangle$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Is there a special name for vectors whose elements are all $0$'s except one $1$? Thanks.

Comment: These are unit vectors, but are more special because there is a "1".

Comment: Do you mean canonical vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the *canonical* or *standard* basis vectors, normally denoted $e_n$ where for the vector $e_n=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n,\ldots,x_k)$, the component $x_n=1$ and $x_i=0$ for all $k\neq n$.

Answer (score 1):

They are called canonical vectors or standard vectors.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't an answer to the question.